# getting wget error while trying to upgrade openwrt kernel

Tags: wget, openwrt

BusyBox v1.22.1 (2014-11-14 10:11:32 CST) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

_______                     ________        __
 |       |.-----.-----.-----.|  |  |  |.----.|  |_
 |   -   ||  _  |  -**|     ||  |  |  ||   _||   _|
 |_______||   __|_____|**|**||________||**|  |____|
          |__| W I R E L E S S   F R E E D O M

---

CHAOS CALMER (Bleeding Edge, unknown)

---

- 1 1/2 oz Gin            Shake with a glassful
- 1/4 oz Triple Sec       of broken ice and pour
- 3/4 oz Lime Juice       unstrained into a goblet.
- 1 1/2 oz Orange Juice
- 1 tsp. Grenadine Syrup

  ---

root@OpenWrt:~# wget https://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/ramips/m
t7620/openwrt-15.05.1-ramips-mt7620-ArcherC20i-squashfs-sysupgrade.bin
wget: not an http or ftp url: https://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/ramips/mt7620/openwrt-15.05.1-ramips-mt7620-ArcherC20i-squashfs-sysupgrade.bin
root@OpenWrt:~#

Answer (score -1):

Replace `https` in your link with `http`:

```
wget http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/ramips/mt7620/openwrt-15.05.1-ramips-mt7620-ArcherC20i-squashfs-sysupgrade.bin
```

Your installed version of wget doesn't support TLS (libopenssl is not installed).

Also, I would change to `/tmp` dir first, so that downloaded image is stored in RAM (you probably don't have enough space in flash):

```
cd /tmp
wget http://...
```

Comment: root@OpenWrt:/tmp# wget http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/ramips
/mt7620/openwrt-15.05.1-ramips-mt7620-ArcherC20i-squashfs-sysupgrade.bin
Connecting to downloads.openwrt.org (78.24.191.177:80)
openwrt-15.05.1-rami 100% |*******************************|  7808k  0:00:00 ETA
root@OpenWrt:/tmp# wget  http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/ramips/mt7620/md5sums
Connecting to downloads.openwrt.org (78.24.191.177:80)
md5sums              100% |*******************************|  3740   0:00:00 ETA
the expected output is name of upgraded firmware then ok